# Create a one to zero-or-one relation on a non-key field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

We use Entity Framework 6 with CodeFirst and an Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

I just created a 1 to 0..1 (one to zero or one) relation between two tables, and it works like a charm. But when adding a second relation, I got into trouble, because the original primary key column was demoted to just a data column, and a surrogate (sequence) primary key column was added. The foreign key constraint is still on the old field.

Code:

```
public class Node
{
    [Key, Column("ID"), Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("POINT_CODE"), Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string PointCode { get; set; }

    // ...columns left out...

    [ForeignKey("PointCode"), Required]
    public NetworkPoint PointCodeFk { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    [Key, Column("POINT_CODE"), Required, StringLength(10)]
    public string PointCode { get; set; }

    // ...columns left out...

    [ForeignKey("PointCode")]
    public Node NodeFk { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : EntityContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Point>()
            .HasOptional(m => m.NodeFk)
            .WithRequired(o => o.PointCodeFk);
    }   

    // ...stuff left out...
}
```

The difference with the working example is, the property `Node.PointCode` has the attribute `Key`, and there is no `Node.Id` column.

When running this example, I get the error message:

> Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Point_NodeFk_Target' in relationship 'Point_NodeFk'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

So I guess EntityFramework now thinks it should be an 1:N relation.

How can this be solved? I can't change the database (although I would like to very much).

Comment: You can't create a one-to-one relation with a FK that is not declared as a PK.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. Do you have a reference to some Microsoft documentation stating that?

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework requires a primary key on each table. You need to add a primary without which EF will complain. So looking at your code Point class require ID, Id ,PointId or PointID property so EF will know it has a primary key. Any of the conventions I showed here as a class property will be acceptable to EF.

Comment: The Point class already has a `[Key]` attribute, so the convention is not necessary (I also removed `IdKeyDiscoveryConvention`). Both classes have a primary key. EF doesn't complain about that. It's the navigational property which EF is confused about.